# How to save entry text to application.current.properties

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Ive saved listviews previously like this so I was hoping I can use the same strategy:

This is my viewmodel where I save all the strings in the class "Notes". Even tho I added the entry binding to the Notes class it doesnt save.:

```
private void Save()
    {
        var art = Memory.Favs;
        art.Add(Notes);            
        Memory.Favs = art;         


    }
```

This is my memory class:

```
    public static class Memory
    {
        public static List<Notes> FavoriteNotes
        {
            get
            {
                if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("favoritenotes"))
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Notes>>(Application.Current.Properties["favoritenotes"].ToString());
                else
                    return new List<Notes>();
            }
            set
            {
                Application.Current.Properties["favoritenotes"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            }
        }
}
}
```

Now to the tricky part, I have an entry in xaml where i need to save data in the Save() void.

My xaml:

```
<Entry  Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderText}"  HeightRequest="200" Text="{Binding TextSaveArt, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: so each item in your ListView contains an Entry that is bound to a property of a Notes object?

Comment: Not exacly. I have a stacklayout with a button and entry on one page to save the content. Then Im supposed to add entry text to each item in a listview on another page. @Jason